# Submitting a hash directly with HTML <form> tag

Tags: html, forms

I need to submit a hash of attributes directly from the form tag.  Is this possible?

```
<form action="/members/1/comments" method="post">
  [some element] {"coordinator\_id"=>"1", "time"=>"1230", "info_link"=>"cnn.com"}
  <submit>Post</submit>
</form>
```

This hash should arrive as 'comment' => {"coordinator_id"=>"1", "time"=>"1230", "info_link"=>"cnn.com"}

Comment: What language are you using on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost possible, but not recommended, you should give your values proper names instead, but here is what you asked for:

```
<form action="/members/1/comments" method="post">
  <input name="comment[coordinator_id]" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input name="comment[time]" type="hidden" value="1230" />
  <input name="comment[info_link]" type="hidden" value="cnn.com" />
  <submit>Post</submit>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, this would be the, but this hash is deeply nested and complicated.  It's already formatted for the server. I just need to send it up without any work just comment[big_nasty_hash].

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but you will have to actually do *work* in this case.